# Как правильно сделать маршрутизацию в web api?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Я начинающий разработчик и пытаюсь написать web api для выбора товара из БД.
Подскажите пожалуйста, возможна ли такая маршрутизация и правильная ли она?
Архитектура видится следующая:
Аутентификация и авторизация пользователя. Каждой паре логин/пароль соответсвует определённый код. Пусть будет 966 для примера.
Далее пользователь переводи по маршруту

1.
`GET http://localhost:6171/api/orders/966/`
    `[HttpGet("{kod}")]`
Выводиться список номенклатуры для выбора.

2.
Далее пользователь выбирает позицию и надо вывести ему доступное количество товара
`GET http://localhost:6171/api/orders/966/GetKolvo?nom=карандаш`

`[HttpGet("{kod}/[action]")]`

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetKolvo([FromRoute]int kod, [FromQuery(Name = nom")]string nom)
{

выведет количество

}
```

3.
Метод, который отображает количество товара
И последний метод, который показывает номер ячейки, где данный товар находится
`GET http://localhost:6171/api/orders/966/GetNomer?nom=карандаш&kol=6`

???

На втором методе я застрял : ( то ли так вообще нельзя сделать/ неправильно , то ли я криво маршрутизирую, но при таком запросе я получаю ошибку 404 и на этом всё : (

**UPD!**
Со вторым контроллером я разобрался.

**Как же правильно делать в этом случае?Как должен выглядеть маршрут для третьего контроллера, когда контроллеру передаются два параметра?**

**GET [http://localhost:6171/api/orders/966/GetNomer?nom=карандаш&kol=6](http://localhost:6171/api/orders/966/GetNomer?nom=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%88&kol=6)**

Заранее спасибо!

Буду рад ссылке на документацию с примером.

Comment: Заказы и позиции это 2 разных контроллера должны быть. На контроллер позиций повесь атрибут [Route("api/orders/{orderId}")]  и всё.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! У меня получается три контроллера. Первый - показывает какие товары доступны покупателю. Второй - какие количества выбранного покупателем товара доступны и Третий - номер ячейки, где выбранный покупателем товар с заданным покупателем количеством находится.

Answer (score 1):

Ура! Разобрался!

В `Startup.cs`  прописал :

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "GetNomer",
template: "api/[controller]/{kod}/{action}");
```

И по ссылке `GET http://localhost:6171/api/orders/966/GetNomer?nom=карандаш&kol=6`
стал возвращаться нужный результат. 
Вроде с маршрутами разобрался.
Спасибо Всем!